# Google Calendar API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm just a hobbyist programmer trying to access Google Calendar. I'm using Android Studio. I've downloaded all the Google Services from the Android SDK manager and set the dependencies. I've also tried following all of Google's documentation of how to do this here: [Google Developers: Calendar API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3), by adding the client libraries manually in the libs folder of the project.

Any time I do any of this the sample scripts say to type:
import com.google.api.etc...
No matter which way I do it "api" always gets highlighted in red and says it cannot be resolved. I have access to drive, maps, and a bunch of other google stuff, just not calendar.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? If so, how did you fix it? If you need more information from me I'd be happy to supply it.
Thanks!

This is what my build.Gradle dependencies currently looks like:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Comment: Post some code and/or screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print here code of your files Gradle.

You need it likes here, and put it into file build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

UPDATE:

Easify method for adding library, then you can put it into file build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev84-1.18.0-rc'
}
```

Comment: The import statement works now, thank you! My only question is how come that's not a selection when adding dependencies in File>>Project Structure? @machei

Comment: Using gradle is just downloading libraries from outside ,after syncing project with files gradle you will get new library from external libraries. 

You need check to compare all files of folder project/libs with external libraries, and make correct for yourself version of these files.

Then copy all files from external to your project/libs, and try to compile without network.