# How to call google calendar api in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, google-calendar-api

I am trying to show the list of google calendar where i can add,edit,and view the event list in mobile app.How can i call the google calendar api in android studio?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Calendar API in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045112/google-calendar-api-in-android-studio)

Comment: Any code attempts ? See [how-to-ask-a-good-question-StackOverlfow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it possible to answer

Comment: I did try the first link you gave me but when i run the application it is not responding any thoughts? Thanks